# Adding Sliding menu Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found

Tags: android

I am trying to add a slide menu to my app I found some on github & I just went for this one https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

 
I renamed library to SlidingMenu as it's the main library 
I added this to my project's `settings.gradle` **>>** `include ':app', ':SlidingMenu'` 
I added this in the app `build.gradle` dependencies **>>**  `compile project(':SlidingMenu')` 
 But i still get this error

```
Gradle 'project_name' project refresh failed
Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

**Update** 
[Link To Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ee9M.png)

Comment: Are you trying to use slide menu as External library or as Module?

Comment: I am trying to implement it in my app to have a slide menu so i guess Module right?

Comment: Have you copied SlidingMenu library inside your main project?

Comment: I only copied the hole file in my project & added these as said should i add SlidingMenu in my project?

Comment: Can you show me the directory structure of your project?

Comment: The possible reason I am think of is, There is no project name "SlidingMenu" in your project root location. May be you have copied the project in wrong directory.

Comment: I have updated it & Just so you know the "SlidingMenu" File you see there (in the main project structure not in SlidingMenu-master got auto created I didn't add it

Comment: I got your problem. You don't need to copy whole project. Just copy SlideMenu Directory in your project root location. Let me know if it works?

Comment: Please check out my answer, For easy way to import module in android studio project.

Comment: it worked but i have an error about the SDK build tool as it is 17.0 & Min is 19.0 & i don't know if changing it in the SlidingMenu `build.gradle` is a good idea maybe you can also help me with that xD

Comment: Yehh you can change it to whichever build tool available. I am using "23.0.1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple steps to import module in android studio project.

Step 1: Goto File>New>Import Module

[image]

Step 2: Select Source Directory
[image]
[image]

Step 3: Rename Module Name if you want,

[image]

Step 4: Add Module in build.gradle file.

[image]

Comment: @IKeepForgettingAccsMail is your all problem resolved?

Comment: There is one error Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: ...AppData\Local\Android\sdk
<a href="openAndroidSdkManager">Open Android SDK Manager</a>

Comment: Have you set compileSdkVersion 23 in slidemenu build.gradle file?

Comment: Try compileSdkVersion 22 or 21.

Comment: Solved thanks a lot just one last thing do you know how to make the app bar always up (showed) when you open the menu so it wont be over it?